# AppCompatActivity, ViewModel and Data Binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

Trying to figure out the Google's recent tools and concepts: [LifecycleActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleActivity.html), [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) and [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html).

So imagine there is a `FooActivity` that extends `AppCompatActivity`(to be able to use Support library) and implements `LifecycleOwner` interface (from reference: required to use LiveData):

**FooActivity.kt:**

```
class FooActivity: AppCompatActivity(), LifecycleObserver {
  ...
```

We set the binding:

```
  ..
  private val mBinding: by lazy {
    DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityFooBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_foo)
  }
  ..
```

We set activity's `ViewModel`, and attach our `barObserver` (which should observe changes of `bar` inside a `ViewModel`, which is just a `List` of `Strings`):

```
  ..
  val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FooViewModel::class.java)
  viewModel.getBars()?.observe(this, barObserver)
  viewModel.init() // changes bar, should trigger Observer's onChanged
  ..
```

And finally we define `barObserver`:

```
  ..
  class BarObserver : Observer<List<String>> {
    override fun onChanged(p0: List<String>?) {
      Log.d("Say", "changed:")
    }
  }
  barObserver = BarObserver()
  ..
```

---

**Questions:**

1. Why does `Observers` `onChange` never triggered?
2. Should one use ``` LifeCycleOwner``getLifecycle ``` instead of using `Observer`?
3. Any other thoughts?

---

**Edit:**
As the [reference states](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html):

> LiveData is a data holder class that can be observed within a given lifecycle. This means that an Observer can be added in a pair with a LifecycleOwner, and this observer will be notified about modifications of the wrapped data only if the paired LifecycleOwner is in active state. LifecycleOwner is considered as active, if its state is STARTED or RESUMED. An observer added via observeForever(Observer) is considered as always active and thus will be always notified about modifications. For those observers, you should manually call removeObserver(Observer).

Changing:

`enter code here`viewModel.getBars()?.observe(this, barObserver)

to:

`viewModel.getBars()?.observeForever(barObserver)`

didn't to the trick. `onChange` still never triggered.

**Edit2:**

**FooActivity.kt**:

replaced with:

```
class FooActivity: AppCompatActivity(), LifecycleRegistryOwner{
  override fun getLifecycle(): LifecycleRegistry {
        var lifecycle = LifecycleRegistry(this)
        lifecycle.addObserver(barObserver)
        return lifecycle
    }
```

**FooViewModel**:

```
  ..
  private var mBar = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
  ..
  mBar.value = listValueOf("1", "2", "3")
  ..
  fun getBar(): LiveData<List<String>>? = mBar
  ..
```

Comment: Are you sure, you are not getting `null` from this `viewModel.getBars()` function.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/chandilsachin/DietTracker, Here you can find a working example of live data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not extending LifecycleActivity then your activity should implement LifecycleRegistryOwner instead of LifecycleObserver. Check out the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html#addendum).

And then you can pass it to liveData.observe(lifecycleOwner, observer)

Comment: That is a good catch. However `Observers` `onChange` still doesn't get triggered. I can confirm that the value of `bar` actually changes (debugged). May be the `Observer` has to be connected somehow with the `getLifecycle`?

Comment: LiveData handles the lifecycle. Make sure you are setting LiveData's value correctly.

Comment: Have a look at **Edit2**. Still missing something?

Comment: Nevermind, a few tweaks and it works. In general, thank you for pointing to the right direction.

Comment: This approach is not valid anymore as `LifecycleRegistryOwner` is now deprecated.

Comment: AppCompatActivity does implement LifecycleOwner

Comment: @NickMowen sure it does now. But this question has been asked back in the days when arch components were still in beta.